# MVC configure using Modal bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using a bootstrap modal in the header - layout page for the entire site

e.g. original code from bootstap

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch Login demo modal
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Login information
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The above code does work.

I modified the button code to link

```
 <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#myModal">Launch login demo modal 2</a>
```

When user clicks on the link the code works, but now the user has access to the url link and could open in a new window/new tab

When user right clicks on the link and choose "open in a new tab" it would fail because this page does not open.e.g.

```
   http://example.com/account/login#myModal 
   http://example.com/blog#myModal
```

Question : Is it possible if user opens in a new tab the url, redirect to 
`http://example.com/account/login` page

a live example fiverr.com (click on join a modal opens) and can also access direct link fiverr.com/join I am using MVC, maybe using a route configurations?

Comment: why down vote what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cat do it with JavaScript. Just get the part of URL after hash and check if it is what you are expected, and then open modal manually:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash == "myModel"){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

Make sure, that code is being executed after page is loaded.